# INTEL XDK + IONIC erro ao instalar apk

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic, app, intel-xdk

Boa tarde,

Estou desenvolvendo um app a fins de estudo...
Fui seguindo o videos tutoriais do FULL STACKER DEVELOPER e modificando conforme queria.
O app funciona em localhost e no intel xdk simulator (usando um banco online), mas depois de gerar a apk, quando instalo ele em um emulador no genymotion, ele abre em uma tela branca e fica por isso.

Já busquei soluções porém não consegui resolver

Link do app (compactei pra .rar)
https://github.com/max10nog/IonicAppTesteMax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu config.xml apaga tudo que tiver de platform android, todas as tags, e depois faz um *ionic platform add android* e faz um novo build.